# Toggle Button in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use a toggle button on my website but it doesn't work (tuggle)

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.583937, 13.963623);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

  }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.slider-button').toggle(function(){
        $(this).addClass('on').html('Quizz');
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass('on').html('Read');
    });
});

</script>
</script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
<header id="site_head">
        <div class="header_cont">
        <h1><a href="#">mr. hurley</a></h1>
        </div>
</header>

<div id="menu" style="float: left; width:20%; height:100%;">
    <ul>
        <li class="first"><a href="#">Search</a>

        <div class="slider-frame">
            <span class="slider-button">OFF</span>
        </div>
        </br>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Offer</a><p> Placeholder</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>

 <div id="map_canvas" style="float: left; width:80%; height:100%"></div>

   <div id="over_map">
    <p>TEst dsfkjsldökjfdslkäfjsdfsdfsdfsdfs</p>
   </div>
</body>


</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, div, h1, h2, h3, p, ul, ol, li, img, header, section, aside, footer, button {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #961b25;
}

a:hover {
    color: #6f92a7;
}

:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: Georgia, Palatino, Palatino Linotype, Times, Times New Roman, serif; 
    font-weight: normal;
} 

h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 28px;
}

.float {
        float:left;
    }

body {
    background: #f6f6ee url(images/bck.jpg);
    font-family : "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }   







header#site_head {
    background: url(bck_head.jpg);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 3px #480508;
    -khtml-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 3px #480508;              
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 3px #480508;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 3px #480508;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fffffb;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

    .header_cont {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .header_cont h1 {
        text-indent:-9999px;
        float: left;
    }

    .header_cont h1 a {
        background: url(logo.png) no-repeat;
        width: 143px;
        height: 45px;
        display: block;
    }

    .header_cont h1 a:hover {
        background-position: 0px -45px;
    }

    nav.head_nav {
        float: right;
        margin-top: 13px;
    }

    nav.head_nav ul li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0px 5px;
    }

    nav.head_nav ul li a {
        color: #f6f6ee;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        padding: 5px 8px;
    }

    nav.head_nav ul li.home a {
        background: #4f1d1e;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;       
        -khtml-border-radius: 10px;             
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    nav.head_nav ul li a:hover {
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #2c0306;
        background: #4f1d1e;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px #2c0306;
        -khtml-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px #2c0306;
        -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px #2c0306; /*-webkit- inset fix*/
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px #2c0306;
        color: #f6f6ee;
    }

    nav.head_nav ul li.rss, nav.head_nav ul li.twitter  {
        position: relative;
        left: -355px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    nav.head_nav ul li.rss a {
        color: #b4676c;
        border-right: 1px solid #903f43;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 20px;
        background: url(images/rss.png) left no-repeat;
        font-size:10px;
    }

    nav.head_nav ul li.twitter a {
        color: #b4676c;
        margin-left: 3px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        background: url(images/twitter.png) left no-repeat;
        font-size:10px;
    }

    nav.head_nav ul li.rss a:hover, nav.head_nav ul li.twitter a:hover  {
        color: #f6f6ee;         
        -moz-border-radius: 0;
        -khtml-border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        -khtml-box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
#map_canvas { height: 80% width:80%}

#menu {
        clear:left;
        float:left;
        width:20%;
        background:#B7B7B7;
        font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border-bottom:1px solid #A8A8A8;
        overflow:scroll;


    }

    #over_map { position: absolute; top: 100px; right: 50px; z-index: 99; width: 20%; height:30%;  background-color/**/: #000000;
    background-image/**/: none;
    opacity: 0.8;

    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    }

.slider-frame {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 84px;
  height: 27px;
  background-color: rgb(246, 249, 251);
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.slider-button {
  display: block;
  width: 43px;
  height: 27px;
  line-height: 27px;
  background: #EDF2F7;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  color: #000;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:11px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.slider-button.on {
  margin-left: 40px;
  background: #EDF2F7;
}
```

I used this as example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vY7SQ/3/

Please help

Comment: It would be more helpful for you to create an example of what's happening on your site on jsFiddle.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Seems to work in your Fiddle

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but you have a random `</script>` tag at the end there.

Comment: the fidle link is the example and the code above is from my implemention

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to separate the jQuery like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.slider-button').toggle(function(){
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(this).html('Quizz');
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        $(this).html('Read');
    }); });
```

Updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vY7SQ/42/)

Edit: Well, I was told I was wrong but scubafly seems to agree with my original suggestion.

I will say this:
Attach the toggle function to `.slider-frame` and apply the changes to `.slider-button`
Way more user-friendly.

Comment: This won't change anything. Method chaining is not only perfectly valid, but encouraged in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If the jQuery script doesn't get called, try removing the  `onload="initialize()"` from the  and call `initialize()` from the `$()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `<span class="slider-button">` to `<span id="slider-button">` and then call `$('#slider-button').toggle(function(){` instead of `$('.slider-button').toggle(function(){`

The Jquery addClass method doesn't replace a class, it just adds it.

Don't forget to change your CSS too.